# Is the set of compact subsets of $R^n$ with the Hausrdorff metric a Heine-Borel space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{K}^n$ be the set of non-empty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the Hausdorff metric:

$$
d_H(A, B) := \max\Big\{ \sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} ||a - b||\,\, , \,\, \sup_{b \in B} \inf_{a \in A} ||a - b|| \Big\},
\\\forall A, B \in \mathcal{K}^n.
$$

We define the **magnitude** of a set $A \in \mathcal{K}^n$ by
$$
||A||:= d(A, \{0\}).
$$
Now, given a set $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{K}^n$, we say that $\mathcal{U}$ is **uniformly bounded** if there exists a number $c = c(\mathcal{U})$ such that
$$
||A|| \leq c, \forall A \in \mathcal{U}.
$$

I would like if the space $(\mathcal{K}^n, d_H)$ satisfy the Heine-Borel property, that is, I want to know if the following is true:

**CLAIM**. A closed, uniformly bounded subset $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{K}^n$ is compact.

Properties I have about the space $(\mathcal{K}^n, d_H):$

1. $(\mathcal{K}^n, d_H)$ is a metric space.
2. It is separable.
3. It is complete.
4. A compact subset $\mathcal{U} \subset (\mathcal{K}^n, d_H)$ is closed and uniformly bounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compactness of a family of closed subsets in a compact space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483997/compactness-of-a-family-of-closed-subsets-in-a-compact-space)